# Fork Choice Rule in Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: protocol, forks, sharding, blockchain-fork, fork-choice-rule

According to the "Fork choice rule" in Ethereum 2.0 (sharding), how to choose a branch in a fork? (A) or (B) ?

> (A) branch, which has the most blocks in it. (similar to "longest
>   chain" rule in PoW)
>
> (B) branch with more attesters across all the blocks.

For example, assuming two following branches in a fork:

```
(1) branch one: including 10 blocks, signed by 8 unique attesters.

(2) branch two: including 8 blocks, signed by 10 unique attesters.
```

**According to the "Fork choice rule" in Ethereum 2.0 (sharding), which above branch in this fork will be chosen? (1) or (2) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fork choice rule in Ethereum 2.0 is called LMD GHOST.

The basic answer to the question is branch 2: the branch with the most attestations/votes.

There are many other details to the fork choice.  For example, proposer boost, and votes are weighted by stake.

---

References:

https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/fork-choice.md

https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03052

https://github.com/protolambda/lmd-ghost

[Visualising the 7-block reorg on the Ethereum beacon chain](https://barnabe.substack.com/p/pos-ethereum-reorg) illustrates an unexpected outcome of the fork choice in action.

Comment: And what if **all parameters** (number of attestations/votes, the weight of votes according to their stake) **are the same**? In a such situation in PoW (where two branches have **same difficulty**) a set of miners work on branch (1) and others on branch (2). And what happens here?

Comment: I think that uncle blocks aren't counted, see here https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/fork-choice.md#get_head

Comment: @upavloff Thanks! Can't remember what made me think of uncles; fixed and updated the answer. The last link I added you'd likely be interested in case you haven't seen.